# NoSuchElementException when using FindElementByAccessibilityId

Tags: c#, android, appium, nosuchelementexception

I'm new to Appium but quite experienced with Selenium.

The first action, clicking on the Element 'Nieuw' is giving no problem, a screen with four choices appears.

After that I'm trying to click on an Element with accessibility id 'Proefitmanager'. In Appium desktop this is giving no problem but in my Appium test I'm getting a NoSuchElement exception. I'm using the Id which is suggested by Appium desktop and my code is comparable with the code generated by the recorder of Appium Desktop although I'm using C# instead of Java.

```
IWebElement nieuw = (IWebElement)driver.FindElementByXPath("(//android.view.View[@content-desc='Nieuw'])[2]");
WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10));
wait.Until(ExpectedConditions.ElementToBeClickable(nieuw));
nieuw.Click();

IWebElement proefrit = (IWebElement)driver.FindElementByAccessibilityId("Proefrit");
wait.Until(ExpectedConditions.ElementToBeClickable(proefrit));
proefrit.Click();
```

My idea is that the element has no focus at the moment of clicking because it is in another frame or so. I tried to use SwitchTo().Frame(0) and Frame(1) but this is given exceptions like:

```
Could not proxy command to remote server. Original error: 404 - undefined`
```

See image from Appium desktop to have an Idea what the app looks like.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Firstly you need to switch from Native View to Web View before clicking on "Proefit" element.

**Here is the sample code in Java:**

```
   Set<String> contextNames = driver.getContextHandles(); 
   for (String contextName : contextNames) {
     System.out.println(contextName); //prints out something like NATIVE_APP or WEBVIEW_1 
    } 
   driver.context(contextNames.toArray()[1]); // set context to WEBVIEW_1
```

2. Then Perform the click operation on the proefit element.

**Here is the sample code in Java:**

```
WebElement proefrit=driver.findElementByAccessibilityId("Proefrit");
wait.Until(ExpectedConditions.ElementToBeClickable(proefrit));
proefrit.click();
```

3.Then switch back to Native Context to continue with the test.

```
driver.context("NATIVE_APP");
```

Comment: Thnx Uday. This is pointing in the right direction, I'm sure about that. I’m searching for hours now to find an example in C# how to Switch context .                                                         
It seems there’s nobody out there using Appium in combination with C#. The appium documentation is giving no examples at all for C#, most of the time it has status “to do” for years now.

Did I made the wrong choice using Appium in combination with C#???

Comment: You can find rich documentation in appium api website for all the functions available. It is also available for C#. It’s a perfect place to lookout for code snippets.

Comment: That's what I was looking, I was too quick with my criticism of the appium documentation. Now I'm trying to handle a failed to start Chromedriver session because of '...._apkpure.com.apk is not installed on device emulator'

Comment: That I have to switch to Webview, does it mean that the app is A hybrid app. How did you noticed that switching to webview is necessary?

Comment: Yes. If at all, the app contains webview, then it is a hybrid app. In the screenshot you have shared earlier , you can notice a tag saying "android.webkit.webview". This confirms that it has webview context.

Comment: Thnx again Uday for your explanation. I will give you the credits for your answer because when debugging I can see that beside the NATIVE_APP context there  also exists a WEBVIEW context. Unfortunately when switching to this WEBVIEW context a : 'Failed to start Chromedriver session' error is raised. This error says appname__apkpure.com.apk is not installed on device emulator-5554. Do you have any idea what causes this, the app itself is installed I can see this and the test can click on the Nieuw link in NATIVE context. What puzzles me is the word 'pure' in the extension in the error message.

Comment: Things to take care of before automating webview . 1. install latest version of Chrome in your mobile device. 2. Specify Mobile Browser as chrome in the desired capabilities. 3) Download the chromedriver supporting the above browser version and specify the path of the chromedriver in the appium desktop before starting the appium server. This might solve your problem.